# How do I load jar resources into META-INF\resources in a derivative project?

Tags: java, tomcat, wicket, war, wicket-1.5

I have a core Web-Base.jar file that has shared components that I use in my web applications.

I'm using Wicket 1.5.  While trying to Solve a problem I was browsing the [javadoc](http://wicket.apache.org/apidocs/1.5/) and found [MetaInfStaticResourceReference](http://wicket.apache.org/apidocs/1.5/org/apache/wicket/request/resource/MetaInfStaticResourceReference.html) which I think could improve my applications efficiency, and simplicity.

How can I set up Web-Base so that my Web Applications that list Web-Base as a dependency have the necessary resources added to 
META-INF/resources/* in the final .war file?

**NOTE:** I'm using

- wicket 1.5.5
- Maven
- Tomcat 6 (just started looking into upgrading to Tomcat 7.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work only on Tomcat 7 because this is supported only in Servlet3 specification.
Put the resources in $PROJECT/src/main/resources/META-INF/resources/ folder.